# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 en MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I have installed the latest version of MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 14.10.

I'm trying to make a connection to a remote database requires public key and get the following error:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at xxxxxxxxx: 3306 xxxxxx-through SSH
>   tunnel at 22 with User xxxxxx Lost connection to MySQL server at
>   'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

What could be going on ?.

Comment: check if you are able to connect from localhost by this user like "mysql -h<server_ip> -u<user> -p"

Comment: Check if your server is listening on the correct address. Usually, changing `bind_address` to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` + `service mysql restart` helps. Note, that it's quick hack for dev environment only, if it is about production - best option is to ask your administrator to fix it.